# Unknown reason for Unexpected stop

Tags: android, android-intent

Below is my code. When I click the "addDebtor" button, it gives me an error:  The application Debt Tracker (process biz.midl.debttracker) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

I can not find any errors in my IDE. I checked the name of the button and it matches. i checked the name of my other activity and it matches as well.

Any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addDebtor);

    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, addDebt.class));

        }
    });
}
```

}

Logcat errors are:

```
09-12 06:03:49.744: D/AndroidRuntime(246): Shutting down VM
09-12 06:03:49.744: W/dalvikvm(246): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {biz.midl.debttracker/biz.midl.debttracker.addDebt}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at biz.midl.debttracker.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:22)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-12 06:03:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 06:08:54.834: D/AndroidRuntime(277): Shutting down VM
09-12 06:08:54.834: W/dalvikvm(277): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {biz.midl.debttracker/biz.midl.debttracker.addDebt}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at biz.midl.debttracker.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:22)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-12 06:08:54.845: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What are logcat errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `addDebt` activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity
            android:name="biz.midl.debttracker.addDebt"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
  </activity>
```

Here `biz.midl.debttracker` is your `packageName`.

Comment: This worked, thank you everyone, I renamed the class but didn't update the manifest

Comment: Glad to help buddy. Accept answer and enjoy. Happy codding.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
 Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addDebtor);

    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent start = new Intent (MainActivity.this,
                                        addDebt.class
                                     );
            startActivity(start);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're either haven't added your Activity in your Manifest file or your addDebt.class should be AddDebt.class, please do follow class name convention.

Comment: assuming the Manifest, because my case sensitivity is correct.. how would one do that, I'm still new to this.

Comment: Look down at Hardy's answer :) You should rename your class to AddDebt by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest

```
<activity android:name="your package.addDebt" />
```